# How to insert record into SQLite3 database via python?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I am very new to python, sql and programming in general and am trying to create a function that takes the two values from the entry box than inserts them into the database and then updates the Treeview to show the updated database.

There are 3 fields in my database `id`, `username` and `password`. I do not know what to put for the ID either as I thought it would auto-increment but when I run the code it requires a value.

Here is my attempt:

```
def add():
    with sqlite3.connect("database.db") as conn:
        c = conn.cursor()
    username=entry_username.get()
    password=entry_password.get()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO logins VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (username, password))
    rows = c.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
        tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row)
    c.close()
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please read this documentation first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have declared column ID with Integer and Primary key then it will automatically auto increment using ROWID. Refer: https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1

```
CREATE TABLE login (
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   username text NOT NULL,
   password text NOT NULL
);
```

And Insert by specifying the column names.

```
INSERT INTO login (username, password) VALUES (?, ?);
```